# Can't connect to MongoDB from the C++ code

Tags: c++, mongodb

Windows 7, msys2, compiler MinGW

Trying to connect to the MongoDB instance from the C++ code. Running `mongod` with the next command:

```
mongod --dbpath ./dev-db --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 --port 27017
```

I can normally connect to this database by `mongo` and in Robomongo.

For the c++ code, I successfully compiled and installed tha last stable Mongo C++ Driver. Code I take from the official [tutorial](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/releases/stable/examples/mongocxx/create.cpp):

```
#include <mongocxx/client.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/instance.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/uri.hpp>

mongocxx::uri uri("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017");
mongocxx::client conn{uri};
auto db = conn["test"];

bsoncxx::document::value restaurant_doc =
    document{} << "address" << open_document << "street"
               << "2 Avenue"
               << "zipcode"
               << "10075"
               << "building"
               << "1480"
               << "coord" << open_array << -73.9557413 << 40.7720266 << close_array
               << close_document << "borough"
               << "Manhattan"
               << "cuisine"
               << "Italian"
               << "grades" << open_array << open_document << "date"
               << bsoncxx::types::b_date{std::chrono::milliseconds{12323}} << "grade"
               << "A"
               << "score" << 11 << close_document << open_document << "date"
               << bsoncxx::types::b_date{std::chrono::milliseconds{121212}} << "grade"
               << "B"
               << "score" << 17 << close_document << close_array << "name"
               << "Vella"
               << "restaurant_id"
               << "41704620" << finalize;
auto res = db["restaurants"].insert_one(std::move(restaurant_doc))
```

And this provide the next error:

```
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'mongocxx::v_noabi::bulk_write_exception'
  what():  No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): [Failed to resolve '127.0.0.1']: generic server error
```

How can I avoid this issue and connect to the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your copy is missing the first line of the example:

`mongocxx::instance inst{};`

See http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-cxx-driver/mongocxx-v3/tutorial/#make-a-connection.  The `mongocxx::instance` constructor and destructor initialize and shut down the driver, respectively, so a `mongocxx::instance` must be created before using the driver and must remain alive for as long as the driver is in use.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is attempting a DNS lookup of 127.0.0.1.  Try changing it to be `localhost` instead (which will resolve to the same IP)

```
mongocxx::uri uri("mongodb://localhost:27017");
```

Comment: Using localhost is not helping. It just shows `[Failed to resolve 'localhost']` instead.